# Excel 2016 'MATCH','ISERROR','IF' formulas with result depending from the match; refering to a cell nearby the result

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, match, cell

As in title, I'm trying to compare two lists and when a formula hits the match I want it to type the text, **but from the cell right next to the found matching cell.**

For example: A list of 5343 positions B1:B5343 has corresponding **reference numbers** in A column (A1:A5343). F1 has a certain number. G1 ought to show the **reference number**, not the match itself.

I've tried to work with this formula:

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(F1;$B$1:$B$5343;0));"";A1)

Where A1 should be the reference cell. Not fluent in Excel enough to know

```
is there a way to refer to a formula result?
is it possible to refer to a cell next to the cell of interest (or few away)? ex.(B-1)54=A54
```

Not sure how can I clarify the problem more than that :) Help me out please!

Eager to read Your answers! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case for [Vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Does the job and works like a charm. My list comparison is simple enough for vlookup to handle that. Thanks Som.

Comment: Glad to help. Mark it as answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

i would probably go for a index match on this, so INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F1,B:B,0),1)
the index part will go get the cell next to it you want, just replace C:C with the column its in

If its not a match use iferror, rather than iserror as well, Its better practice.

SO : IFERROR( INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F1,B:B,0),1) ,"NO MATCH)

[Heres a tutorial](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)

Comment: google index match for tutorials, better than a vlookup as you could go backwards essentially, also there is talk it uses less memory